# Show element on hover and pause autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery

thanks for taking the time looking at this problem! I'm having this problem, I have four images with auto play showing only one at a time and need to do the following:

- When the mouse is over the arrows, the current autoplay image should hide and show the image of the hovered arrow (For example if the autoplay just started showing the top image and I hover the bottom arrow the image at the top should hide and show me the one I'm hovering), and when the mouse is out it should hide it continuing with the autoplay.

I tried with many different things but still can't achieve the effect.

The code is the following one:

**HTML**

```
<div id="controllers">
                    <img class="images" id="topFeature" src="images/topFeature.png" alt="" title="">
                    <div id="topArrow"></div>
                    <img class="images" id="rightFeature" src="images/rightFeature.png" alt="" title="">
                    <div id="rightArrow"></div>
                    <img class="images" id="bottomFeature" src="images/bottomFeature.png" alt="" title="">
                    <div id="bottomArrow"></div>
                    <img class="images" id="leftFeature" src="images/leftFeature.png" alt="" title="">
                    <div id="leftArrow"></div>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#controllers #topArrow{

    background: url("../images/arrows.png") left top no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11em;
    left: 17em;
    z-index: 0;
}

#controllers #rightArrow{
    background: url("../images/arrows.png") left -71px no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16.5em;
    left: 23em;
    z-index: 0;
}

#controllers #bottomArrow{
    background: url("../images/arrows.png") left -40px no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 23em;
    left: 17em;
    z-index: 0;
}

#controllers #leftArrow{
    background: url("../images/arrows.png") left -120px no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16.5em;
    left: 11em;
    z-index: 0;
}

#controllers #topArrow:hover, #topArrowEffect{
    background: url("../images/arrows.png") right top no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11em;
    left: 16.9em;
}

#controllers #rightArrow:hover, #rightArrowEffect{
    background: url("../images/arrows.png") right -71px no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16.5em;
    left: 23em;
}

#controllers #bottomArrow:hover, #bottomArrowEffect{
    background: url("../images/arrows.png") right -40px no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 23em;
    left: 16.9em;
}

#controllers #leftArrow:hover, #leftArrowEffect{
    background: url("../images/arrows.png") right -120px no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16.5em;
    left: 11em;
}

#controllers img#topFeature{
    position: absolute;
    top: -5em;
    z-index: 1;
}

#controllers img#rightFeature{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5.5em;
    left: 25em;
    z-index: 1;
}

#controllers img#bottomFeature{
    position: absolute;
    top: 19em;
    left: -10em;
    z-index: 1;
}

#controllers img#leftFeature{
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: -30em;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var images = $('.images');
var current = 0;

images.hide();

Slider();

function Slider(){
    $(images[current]).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

    switch(current){
        case 0: $('#topArrow').attr('id', 'topArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', 'topArrow');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
                break;

        case 1: $('#rightArrow').attr('id', 'rightArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', 'rightArrow');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
                break;

        case 2: $('#bottomArrow').attr('id', 'bottomArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', 'bottomArrow');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
                break;

        case 3: $('#leftArrow').attr('id', 'leftArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', 'leftArrow');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
                break;
    }

    $(images[current]).queue(function(){
        current = current < images.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
        Slider();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
}

    $( "#bottomArrow" ).mouseenter(function(){
    $( "#bottomArrow" ).attr('id', 'bottomArrowEffect');
    images[current].hide();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $( "#bottomArrow" ).attr('id', 'bottomArrowEffect');
    images[current].show();
});


});
```

The live example is here: [Live example](http://www.orsileonel.com.ar/juoku/index.html)

My problem is that I can't achieve the effect, I made an example with the bottom arrow and it only appears as hovered but don't hide and show the images, I've been trying many different things but still don't working fine.

**Edit 1:**

Here I've been trying another code with the right arrow hover but still not working:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
    var images = $('.images');
    var current = 0;

    images.hide();

    Slider();

    function Slider(){
        $(images[current]).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

        switch(current){
            case 0: $('#topArrow').attr('id', 'topArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', 'topArrow');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
                    break;

            case 1: $('#rightArrow').attr('id', 'rightArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', 'rightArrow');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
                    break;

            case 2: $('#bottomArrow').attr('id', 'bottomArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', 'bottomArrow');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
                    break;

            case 3: $('#leftArrow').attr('id', 'leftArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', 'leftArrow');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
                    break;
        }       

        $(images[current]).queue(function(){
            current = current < images.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
            if(active = true)
                Slider();
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    }

    function nonSlider(){
        $(images[current]).hide();

        switch(current){
            case 0: $('#topArrow').attr('id', 'topArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', 'topArrow');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
                    break;

            case 1: $('#bottomArrow').attr('id', 'bottomArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', 'bottomArrow');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
                    break;

                    break;

            case 3: $('#leftArrow').attr('id', 'leftArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                $(this).attr('id', 'leftArrow');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
                    break;
        }       

        $(images[current]).queue(function(){
            current = current < images.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
            nonSlider();
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    }


    $("#rightArrow").on("hover", function(){
        $(this).attr('id', 'rightArrowEffect');
        active = false;
        nonSlider();
        $(images[1]).show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).attr('id', 'rightArrow');
        active = false;
        Slider();
    });

});
```

**Edit 2**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var images = $('.images');
                var current = 0;
                var hovered = false;

                images.hide();

                Slider();

                $('.arrow').each(function () {
                    $(this).on('hover', function () {
                        hovered = true;

                        images[current].dequeue().fadeOut(200);

                        var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s/);
                        var selectedImage = $('#'+classes[1]+'Feature');

                        selectedImage.stop().fadeIn(300);

                        console.log(selectedImage);
                    });
                });


                function Slider(){
                    $(images[current]).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');

                    switch(current){
                        case 0: $('#topArrow').attr('id', 'topArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                            $(this).attr('id', 'topArrow');
                            $(this).dequeue();
                        });
                                break;

                        case 1: $('#rightArrow').attr('id', 'rightArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                            $(this).attr('id', 'rightArrow');
                            $(this).dequeue();
                        });
                                break;

                        case 2: $('#bottomArrow').attr('id', 'bottomArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                            $(this).attr('id', 'bottomArrow');
                            $(this).dequeue();
                        });
                                break;

                        case 3: $('#leftArrow').attr('id', 'leftArrowEffect').delay(3800).queue(function(){
                            $(this).attr('id', 'leftArrow');
                            $(this).dequeue();
                        });
                                break;
                    }       

                    $(images[current]).queue(function(){
                        current = current < images.length - 1 ? current + 1 : 0;
                        if(!hovered)
                            Slider();
                        $(this).dequeue();
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Post the part of html markup on which you are working.

Comment: @shaunakde Hi! I added the HTML markup, thanks for the help!